# WP Парсит ли robots shortcode правильно?

Tags: php, wordpress, парсер

Подскажите, очень важный теоретический вопрос - Что видит Google бот при обработке текста в котором вставлен [шорткод](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/shortcodes) ? Предположим, через шорткод в seo текст страницы добавляется некий кастомный блок комментариев контент менеджером. Увидит ли бот при парсинге страницы результат шортода, или же он прочитает его как вставку по типу `[customReviwes]` ?  Как это можно проверить ?

Answer (score 1):

Увидит, не переживайте. Например при использовании функции `the_content()` WordPress запускает несколько фильтров которые обрабатывают текст, поступающий из редактора. Эти фильтры обрабатывают контент перед его отправкой в браузер, вся обработка естественно происходит на сервере, потому Вам не о чем переживать. Функция [do_shortcode()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/do_shortcode) собственно и находит зарегестрированные шорткоды в переданном тексте и затем обрабатывает их.